# c# GDIPlus not found

Tags: c#, gdi+

Hello I am trying to develop an application using c# and I am using the System.Drawing DLL. However, I get an exception for when I run it pretty much saying the System.Drawing.GDIPlus DLL was not found when I am including the System.Drawing DLLin my build. Are there any ways to do this or am I hopeless and need to figure out a workaround.

Comment: What kind of app are you building? For example, a WPF app gets these objects from PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll, and uses a variety of System.Windows.* namespaces.

Comment: at this point, the build is just for the WebGL platform. I was using Unity but I'm trying to figure out what to switch over to, I can only get a standalone version working because of the GDI+ error.